# How to save data to multiple tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I am using Devise for authentication in my app and got a model named as "Users". I created an another model for Company informations. I generated the migration with references and everything is okay.

I want to add user informations to users table and company informations to companies table in same registration view.

Also both users and companies tables got the same field as "name".

I tried to specify it as ;

```
<%= f.text_field :company["name"], autocomplete: "company_name" %>

<%= f.text_field :company[:name], autocomplete: "company_name" %>

<%= f.text_field :companies[:name], autocomplete: "company_name" %>
```

And i got the errors ;

```
undefined method `' for #<User:0x00007fd5588cb588>

no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

I think somehow i should override devise_controller but i want to learn the general practice for these kind of situations.

Sum: I want to save data to different tables which has same column names in database.

Comment: What association do you have between users and companies? Please, add models code to the question. And the whole form code too - it is unclear, what and when you're trying to create

Comment: I have a company_id field in my Users table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `user belongs_to company` and you want to save user and their associated company from one form submit, you can use `fields_for` for this

```
<%= f.fields_for :company do |cf| %>
  <%= cf.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

This will require `accepts_nested_attributes_for :company` in User.

Comment: Thank you. I got the main idea but i need to have only one submit button.

Comment: @Zogimu: yes, this solution does this

Comment: So i don't need to have a cf.submit button ?

Comment: @Zogimu: no, you don't. Read up on fields_for/accepts_nested_attributes_for. Good stuff.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why but  `<%= f.fields_for :company do |cf| %>
            <%= cf.text_field :company_name, autocomplete: "company_name" %>
        <% end %>`   this code is not rendered on view without any errors.

Comment: @Zogimu: weird. It should render. Inspect the page source. I'd wager that the markup is there, it's just rendered invisible by your styling (or something like that)

Comment: There is nothing under page source. I can add html inputs but this ruby code is not rendered. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @Zogimu: ah, maybe `user.company` is nil? In which case do `user.build_company` (or similar) before rendering the form.

Comment: Okay changing `<%= f.fields_for :company` to `<%= f.fields_for :company_attributes` and permitting company_attributes with devise_parameter_sanitizer is solved the rendering problem. It's not working as company but when i change it to company_attributes it works.Weird

Comment: Congrats for sorting this out!